# From the "Review Close Votes" workflow, How do I recommend that StackOverflow questions be migrated to Apple.SE?

Tags: support

Specifically, when reviewing "close votes", I like that the "close for being off-topic" dialog suggests sites for migration, but [some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478244/symlink-to-the-latest-version-formula-directory?noredirect=1) deserve to be migrated to Apple.SE and that is not an option in the dialog.  How can I suggest these question be migrated to Apple.SE?  (You may feel that this specific question was appropriately migrated to SuperUser.com but this is just one of several examples I've seen where I would vote to migrate to Apple.SE.)

It is not a good workflow for reviewers to have to step out of the "close votes" process to flag for moderator attention and even if it were it runs the substantial risk (as in the question cited) that the vote will be finalized to close and migrate to another site before the moderators even get to look at it.

Comment: Flag with `Other` reason

Comment: @slhck, yes, except I think it belongs on Apple.SE more than in Super User.  The answer has to do with `brew` which is specific to Apple / Mac

Comment: +1 I'm in complete agreement - all the current process does is create extra effort for both reviewers AND mods instead of the ability to point them at _more appropriate_ SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

Flag for moderator attention, and use the "other" reason (allows you to enter text). Explain where you think it belongs and why.

The list you're presented with when you select off-topic is determined based on most common migrations. It occasionally, but infrequently, changes as needed.

Comment: "Flag for moderator attention" is not an option presented in the "Review Close Votes" workflow.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

You're now talking about `Reviewing Closed Votes`. 
Off topic means it doesn't belong on this site. 
It's the moderator's job to choose wether it should be moved elsewhere or not. You can suggest it. That's where the flag comes into play.

Simply close it as off topic. **Then** flag it for moderator attention. (See below)

---

You simply click on the *flag* option under the question. Then when the flagging options appear, you do this :

[image]

Don't forget to *explain why* it should be migrated.

Comment: "Flag for moderator attention" is not an option presented in the "Review Close Votes" workflow.

Comment: @OldPro This infomartion was added after my answer. I edited. Thanks for the info.